# Echo of array doesn't do paragraphs on the right places

Tags: php, arrays

I know this isn’t a very useful question for most people but I have dedicated a lot of time to solve a small problem and I didn’t get the results that I wanted, so I need your help:

```
<?php   
$lines = file('temphum.txt');
$result = array_reverse($lines);
for($i=0; $i<count($result);$i=$i+4){
 $cenas= $result[$i]."ºC";
 $contentsite= nl2br($cenas);
 echo $contentsite ;
}
?>
```

This code prints this:

```
25ºC24
ºC23
ºC22
ºC21
ºC
```

Instead of this:

```
25ºC
24ºC
23ºC
22ºC
21ºC
```

What is the problem?

Comment: By default, `file` leaves the line endings at the end the values it reads, so you effectively have `24[newline]ºC` here and are applying `nl2br` to that. Use the flag `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` in your `file` call, and then put a line break _after_ your appended `ºC` yourself. And the next time, please go read the manual on the functions you are using before asking.

Comment: Can you show use what the contents of `temphum.txt` is?

Comment: @CBroe thanks, and yes i read the documentations (file, echo and arrays), but when you are a beginner you are not completely sure what you actually have to use. And if i didn't read the documentation i would not been able to do the code that i did( evan if it is no clompletely correct). Thanks for the advice anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You append the *°C* sign after the newline at the end of the string.

```
<?php   
$lines = file('temphum.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$result = array_reverse($lines);
for($i=0; $i<count($result);$i=$i+4){
    echo $result[$i]."ºC"."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. i tried the <br> but i thougt that i had to close php and open again after that because is html... it was a great help because i will never remember the "FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES" to remove the "spaces".